# Change Extents on Overview Map

Tags: arcgis-flex-viewer

Does anyone know how to change the extents on the overview map in Flex Viewer 2.5?
I have a basemap of a single country and my overview map still wants to show me the world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extent of the overview map is set in the updateOverviewExtentFromMap() function in OverviewMapComponent.mxml . By default it is always 3 times the extent of your main map.

```
private function updateOverviewExtentFromMap():void
{
    overviewMap.extent = map.extent.expand(3);
    overviewGraphic.geometry = map.extent;
}
```

You could either hardcode this to your country, or make sure that it never goes outside the extent of that country.